# JS object functions leak through

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry for the basic question, I'm not very good with JS, so I'm sure I'm missing the obvious solution. I'm using this code:

http://mrlecko.github.io/markovpoet/js/nickmarkov.js

and doing parse_text("hey watch me"), which crashes with "push is not a function" on Firefox dev. I debugged a bit, and it's because `result["watch"]` returns a function rather than the value I added.

How can I get a clean key/val map, like a Python dictionary, so it won't be a minefield of lookups?

Comment: what browser are you using?  Newer browsers won't expose functions like `watch` to a `for .. in` or `Object.keys` test.

Comment: Firefox developer edition (34).